# unable to open include file sstream.h in c++

Tags: c++, header

I am trying to use header file `sstream.h` Below is my code segment

```
  #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <sstream>

 int main ()
{
string mystr;
float price=0;
int quantity=0;

cout << "Enter price: ";
getline (cin,mystr);
stringstream(mystr) >> price;
cout << "Enter quantity: ";
getline (cin,mystr);
stringstream(mystr) >> quantity;
cout << "Total price: " << price*quantity << endl;
return 0;
  }
```

But i am getting following error

```
unable to open include file sstream.h
```

Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you copy-paste properly? Is that exact same error you get?

Comment: What's your compiler? And are you sure it is not the non-standard `conio.h` that is missing?

Comment: check to see if you can use the  `stringstream::` accessor in the body without the header include

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of issues, try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
 std::string st = "23 53";
 int result;
 std::stringstream(st) >> result;
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Some:

- `getchar` instead of `getch`
- `<cstdio>` for `getchar`
- qualify `string` and `stringstream` with `std::`
- `sstream`, not `sstream.h`

Comment: but then `getchar` should be in `std`. it being in the global namespace is just an implementation artifact.

Comment: @unkulunkulu I didn't know that. So you're saying there's a `using std::getchar` somewhere in the header?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, on the contrary, there's `#include <stdio.h> namespace std { using ::getchar; }`

Comment: Thanks @Luchian when i run your code i get the following 2 error 1. unable to open include file sstream.h and 2.unable to open include file cstdio.h, i am using borland C++ version 5.0

Comment: @AshiqurRahman Then your C++ compiler installation is broken. Delete and reinstall it.

Comment: @AshiqurRahman are you trying to include `sstream.h` or `sstream`? The error says it's `sstream.h`, although I specifically said you should include `sstream`...

Comment: yes i am using sstream but the error says sstream.h i think my compiler is not working properly.

Comment: Thanks anyway @Luchian Grigore